# Problems with .cancel() in Android CountDownTimer

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

I have problems with the Android CountDownTimer.

I am trying to learn myself some JAVA/Android, and have started on a simple app for my self to use when I brew coffee. I cannot get the `.cancel ()` function for the CountDown Timer to work. I have read several threads on this and other forums.

My Java Code:

```
package jandidrik.kaffe;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnSeekBarChangeListener {

private SeekBar WaterSeekBar, CoffeeSeekBar, BloomingSeekBar, BrewingSeekBar;
private TextView WaterText, CoffeeText, BloomingText, BrewingText, TimerText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    WaterSeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.WaterSeekBar);
    CoffeeSeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.CoffeeSeekBar);
    BloomingSeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.BloomingSeekBar);
    BrewingSeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.BrewingSeekBar);

    WaterText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.WaterText);
    CoffeeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CoffeeText);
    BloomingText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.BloomingText);
    BrewingText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.BrewingText);
    TimerText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Timer);

    WaterSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
    CoffeeSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
    BloomingSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
    BrewingSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);

    WaterSeekBar.setProgress(1000);
    WaterText.setText(Integer.toString(WaterSeekBar.getProgress()));
    CoffeeSeekBar.setProgress(63);
    CoffeeText.setText(Integer.toString(CoffeeSeekBar.getProgress()));

    Long Minutes = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMinutes(BrewingSeekBar.getProgress());
    Long Seconds = BrewingSeekBar.getProgress() - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(Minutes);
    BrewingText.setText("" + String.format("%01d:%02d", Minutes, Seconds));
}

@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar Bar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
    switch (Bar.getId()) {
        case R.id.WaterSeekBar:
            WaterText.setText(Integer.toString(progress));
            break;
        case R.id.CoffeeSeekBar:
            CoffeeText.setText(Integer.toString(progress));
            break;
        case R.id.BloomingSeekBar:
            BloomingText.setText(Integer.toString(progress));
            break;
        case R.id.BrewingSeekBar:
            Long Minutes = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMinutes(BrewingSeekBar.getProgress());
            Long Seconds = BrewingSeekBar.getProgress() - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(Minutes);
            BrewingText.setText("" + String.format("%01d:%02d", Minutes, Seconds));
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar Bar) {
}

@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar Bar) {
}

public void Brew(View V) {

    final Button BrewButton = (Button) V;
    final String ButtonText = BrewButton.getText().toString();

    CountDownTimer Count = new CountDownTimer(BrewingSeekBar.getProgress() * 1000, 1000) {

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            Long Minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished);
            Long Seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(Minutes);

            TimerText.setText("" + String.format("%01d:%02d", Minutes, Seconds));

            int VibrateTime = BrewingSeekBar.getProgress() - BloomingSeekBar.getProgress();

            if ((TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished)) == VibrateTime) {
                Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                // Vibrate 500ms
                v.vibrate(500);

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Blooming is finnished!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            TimerText.setText("Finished!");
        }
    };

    if (ButtonText.equals("Start Brewing!")) {
        Count.start();
        BrewButton.setText("Stop Timer!");
    } else {
        Count.cancel();
        BrewButton.setText("Start Brewing!");
    }
}
}
```

My XML Code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:keepScreenOn="true">
tools:context="jandidrik.kaffe.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Adjust Amount of water (ml)"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    />

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/WaterSeekBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:max="1200"
    android:progress="1000"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/WaterText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="14"
    android:text="1000"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    />

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Adjust Amount of coffee (g)"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/CoffeeSeekBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:max="100"
    android:progress="63"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/CoffeeText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="63"
        android:layout_weight="14"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        />

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="52dp"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Set the blooming time (s)"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/BloomingSeekBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:max="60"
        android:progress="30"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/BloomingText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="30"
        android:layout_weight="14"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        />

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Set the total brewing time (m:ss("
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/BrewingSeekBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:max="480"
        android:progress="240"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/BrewingText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="4 min 0 s"
        android:layout_weight="14"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        />

</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/BrewButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Start Brewing!"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:onClick="Brew"

    />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<Chronometer
    android:id="@+id/Timer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:format="%s:%s"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    />
</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: "can't get it to work"... what happens? the timer just doesn't stop counting down? be very specific about what you expected vs. what you see - it will help us help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to stop wrong instance of `CountDownTimer`.
The simplest way to fix your code is just moving out `Count` out of method.

```
private CountDownTimer currentCount;
public void Brew(View v) {
    final Button BrewButton = (Button) V;
    final String ButtonText = BrewButton.getText().toString();

    if (ButtonText.equals("Stop Timer!") && currentCount != null) {
        currentCount.cancel();
        currentCount = null;
        BrewButton.setText("Start Brewing!");
        return;
    }

    currentCount = new CountDownTimer(BrewingSeekBar.getProgress() * 1000, 1000) {

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            Long Minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished);
            Long Seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(Minutes);

            TimerText.setText("" + String.format("%01d:%02d", Minutes, Seconds));

            int VibrateTime = BrewingSeekBar.getProgress() - BloomingSeekBar.getProgress();

            if ((TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished)) == VibrateTime) {
                Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                // Vibrate 500ms
                v.vibrate(500);

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Blooming is finnished!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            TimerText.setText("Finished!");
        }
    };

    currentCount.start();
    BrewButton.setText("Stop Timer!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Each time BrewButton is clicked, a call will be made to the Brew() method another 'new' CountDownTimer will be allocated and assigned to your `Count` variable.  Whether you move this variable declaration out of the scope of the `Brew` method, or not, will not change this.  Consequently, the call to `.cancel()` will likely be made on the incorrect CountDownTimer object.

Your program's reference to the original CountDownTimer object is lost, but it's still running until it is garbage collected and will still call it's .onTick() and .inFinish() methods.

The solution is to ensure you're only hanging onto one CountDownTimer object and ensure that you're referencing that object (and not allocating a new one) when the user is pressing the BrewButton a second time to stop timing.

Perhaps you would put `Count` into class scope, initialize to NULL, and then only instantiate a new one in the Brew() method when `Count` is NULL.  Then, in your `if (StartBrewing)` statement, ensure that you're resetting `Count` back to NULL after your call to `Count.cancel()`

I'll leave the precise code to do this as an exercise for the reader.